# How to simulate a bump gesture on ios simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Does anyone know how to simulate a bump gesture on the ios simulator? Is this even possible? I'm using xcode 4.6.

Any help on this topic would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So final answer is its simply not possible since the ios simulator does not have an accelerometer. iSimulate is an alternative to this issue per Mike C.

Answer (score 2):

I use [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) to use the accelerometer in the simulator. It consists of a simulator only library you link with and an app you run on your device. When you start your app in the simulator, the app on your device will connect to it on the local network and relay all touch & accelerometer events to the simulator.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the only alternative after searching on google, but for $14.99? Thanks for sharing tho.